# Creating an intance of static class inside of different class

Tags: clojure

I'm writing a Clojure application, which uses BouncyCastle to encrypt data when being transmitted over the internet. However, BouncyCastle has some very strangely written classes, especially one called ECCurve (elliptic curve). It is just an abstract class extended by two classes Fp and F2m (different kinds of curves). However, these are written just as public static classes inside ECCurve (rather than being in separate files).

So the question is: when I'm creating an instance of a class declared as static inside of a different, abstract class, how do I refer to it? I've tried this:

```
(def curve (new ECCurve.Fp params)) ; naive, I know (ECCurve is imported btw)
(def curve (new ECCurve/Fp params))
(def curve (new (. ECCurve Fp) params))
(def curve (new (ECCurve/Fp) params))
(def curve (new org.bouncycastle.math.ec.ECCurve.Fp params))
```

... but neither of these work (compiler says ClassNotFoundException was thrown). Any idea, how to do this right?

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ECCurve$Fp` is the real classname. Javac lets you use `ECCurve.Fp` as basically syntactic sugar.